# Why the href attribute is not getting set in followinng scenario?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, smarty

I'm using jQuery Colorbox library. I'm not able to a set the **href** attribute value of anchor tag. Can you help me in setting the value? If I print the value in alert it's printing correct href attribute value. My code is as follows:

```
<a class="edit_user_transaction_status c-btn" updatehref="{$control_url}{$query_path}?op=edit_user_transaction&page={$page}&txn_no={$user_transaction_details.transaction_no}&transaction_data_assign={$user_transaction_details.transaction_data_assign}&user_id={$user_id}{if $user_name!=''}&user_name={$user_name}{/if}{if $user_email_id!=''}&user_email_id={$user_email_id}{/if}{if $user_group!=''}&user_group={$user_group}&{/if}{if $user_sub_group!=''}&user_sub_group={$user_sub_group}{/if}{if $from_date!=''}&from_date={$from_date}{/if}{if $to_date!=''}&to_date={$to_date}{/if}{if $transaction_status!=''}&transaction_status={$transaction_status}{/if}{if $transaction_no!=''}&transaction_no={$transaction_no}{/if}" href="#updatePopContent">Update</a>

<div class="hidden">
  <div id="updatePopContent" class="c-popup">
    <h2 class="c-popup-header">Transaction</h2>
    <div class="c-content">         
      <h3>Are you sure to change status?</h3>
      <a href="#"class="c-btn">No</a><a href="" class="c-btn edit_transaction_status" id="update_url">Yes</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   

 $(".edit_user_transaction_status").click(function(e) { 
  //$.colorbox.close(); 
    var update_url = $(this).attr('updatehref');
    $('#update_url').attr('href', update_url);
    $(".edit_user_transaction_status").colorbox({inline:true, width:666});   

    $(".c-btn").bind('click', function(){
      $.colorbox.close();
    });
  });

  });
  </script>
```

I'm not able to set the value of href attribute (i.e. update_url) to the anchor tag having id **update_url**. Can you help me in this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add console lines to see where it is failing?

Comment: check whats the value of update_url using console or alert

Comment: It's not giving me any error in console of firebug and if I print the value of href attribute it says "undefined"

Comment: if you do a `console.log(update_url)`, right after the `var update_url` line, what do you get?

Comment: After setting the value of update_url I printed it using alert it's giving me the desired value.

Comment: Do you have multiple of these elements?

Comment: @KevinB: I was just about to remove it hoping nobody would have seen. But no. Oversight mate :)

Comment: @KevinB:No, I'm having only single element with id update_url.

Comment: updatehref is not valid attribute, use data-* HTML5 attribute or jq data() object instead. But this should not be related to your issue

Comment: the href **IS** set if you run the above code right away

Comment: Ok, break your code down into smaller pieces. You suspect the attr isn't being set. Ok, take out the click event and all the extra elements and just have two elements, one with the weird attribute and one that gets the value of said attribute. here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/uCLaa/ Obviously something else is wrong. Start by replacing the attribute in the fiddle with what your attribute contains.

Comment: @A. Wolff, it completely doesnt matter if an attr is "valid"

Comment: @davidkonrad in some browser and depending DOCTYPE, that could matter

Comment: @A.Wolff if that Were a problem we'd be having a serious issue with backwards compatibility of data-attributes too, but we're not.

Comment: @KevinB As i'm aware of, older IE remove non valid attribute before rendering DOM. Custom data-attributes are HTML5 valid, so if DOCTYPE is correct, there is no backward compatibility issue. Am I correct?

Comment: @ A. Wolff , which ones? Its only important regarding validation of the html

Comment: the thing is, data attributes even work in Ie6, where HTML5 wasn't even a thought. It just requires that you be in standards mode, so as long as you're not in quirks mode, custom attributes should work (even if they are invalid). In quirks mode, all bets are off.

Comment: @davidkonrad i was thinking about <IE7. But anyway, we are all agree this is not OP's issue here

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a data attribute instead of a made-up one (should work, but better to use data. Also, know that firebug, etc. doesn't always change when something is dynamically updated ive found. You can always console.log($('.edit_user_transaction_status').attr('href')) to check the final value:

```
<a class="edit_user_transaction_status c-btn" data-updateHref="{$control_url}... href="#updatePopContent">Update</a>

$(".edit_user_transaction_status").click(function(e) { 
//$.colorbox.close(); 
var update_url = $(this).data('updateHref');
$('#update_url').attr('href', update_url);
$(".edit_user_transaction_status").colorbox({inline:true, width:666});   

$(".c-btn").bind('click', function(){
  $.colorbox.close();
});
```

});